# passing variable back from the server to ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

User fills input texts, presses the button Submit. The data sends to the server to be stored and result returned back. Fancybox window with result appears. My question is: how to display the result $res1 in the fancybox?

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"index/success",
    async:false,
    data:{ name:name, password:password},
    success:function ()
    {
        var html='$res1 from the server should be here instead of this string';//var html=$res1.
        $.fancybox(
            {
                content: html,//fancybox with content will be displayed on success resul of ajax
                padding:15,
            }
        );
    }
});
```

=========================

OK, still doesn't work (returns in the fancybox the whole page+ the word "hello" on top instead of the message "hello"). Below is my update regarding the answers below, that doesn't work properly:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $res1="hello";... // handle logic here
    echo $res1; // print $res1 value. I want to display "hello" in the fancybox.
?>
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index/success",
    async: false,
    data: {
        name: name,
        password: password
    },
    success: function (html) {
       $.fancybox(
       {
         content: html,//returns hello+page in the fancybox

          //if I use the string below instead of the upper one, the fancybox shows "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."
         // content: console.log(html) 


         padding:15,
    }
});
```

=============
**New update:**
Fixed!!! The problem was the data ( "hello" in the example above) was sent to the template in the framework, and template was displayed. 
That's why. 
Fixed.
Thank you.
Everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using PHP:

**PHP**:

```
<?php
    ... // handle logic here
    echo $res1; // print $res1 value
?>
```

**AJAX**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index/success",
    async: false,
    data: {
        name: name,
        password: password
    },
    success: function (html) {
        // given that you print $res1 in the backend file,
        // html will contain $res1, so use var html to handle
        // your fancybox operation
        console.log(html);
    }
});
```

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, still doesn't work properly. I put my updated code in the question body right after the question. It returns the absolutely whole html page + the message instead of the message only.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"index/success",
  async:false,
  data:{ name:name, password:password},
  success:function(html){ // <------- you need an argument for this function
    // html will contain all data returned from your backend.
    console.log(html);
  }
});
```